# Transposing two fields in awk

Tags: awk

Suppose that a file looks like:

```
a|b|c|d
a|b|c|d
...
a|b|c|d
```

How do I transpose two fields, for example:

```
c|b|a|d
c|b|a|d
...
c|b|a|d
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another solution: swap the first and third field, then print:

```
awk -F '|' '{ temp=$1; $1=$3; $3=temp; print }' data.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

At least if memory serves, something on this general order should work:

```
BEGIN { FS="|"; }

    { printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n", $3, $2, $1, $4); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Jerry was 'right', but there is a much more concise way to accomplish this

`awk -F\| '{print $3FS$2FS$1FS$4}' input.csv`

FS stands for Field Separator You Could change it to $3" "$2" ", etc.. if its easier